Puzzled by conditions of prop1.29 from Markov Chains and Mixing times by Levin and Peres
The book proposed and proved that the transition matrix P has a unique stationary distribution if and only if there is a unique essential communicating class.
prop 1.29
However, the proof involves in applying prop 1.28, which only works for the finite case.
PROPOSITION 1.28. If $\pi$ is stationary for the finite transition matrix P, then
$\pi(y_0)$ = 0 for all inessential states $y_0$.
prop 1.28
My puzzle is, does PROPOSITION 1.29 only work for the finite case? Or actually it is universal? If so, how to bridge the gap between finite and infinite?
I'd really appreciate your help!

Yes, proposition $1.29$ only holds for finite chains, which are the only ones dealt with in chapter $1$ of Levin and Peres's book, although I agree that the authors could have done a better job of making this clear.  Infinite chains can comprise a single essential communicating class whose states are all null recurrent.  For such chains a stationary distribution does not exist. The symmetric random walk on the integers is one example of such a chain.
For chains with a countably infinite state space, there is a corresponding theorem which says that such a chain has a unique stationary distribution if and only if it has a unique positive recurrent communicating class. Chains with countably infinite state spaces are treated in chapter 21 of Levin and Peres's book.

That was really clear and helpful! Thanks so much:)
